# RAIL favicon.ico default path issue. How do you overwrite the default path for a favicon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon

We have a multi-tenacy CMS running on RAILS. When Google reads sitemap.xml It pulls the default favicon.ico in our system. That is the icon for the CMS itself. We need it to show the icon for the domain it is referencing. My thought was to put the ICON in the DB and have it serve as system serves any other data. However RAILS just servers the default path of the physical file.

Any Ideas on how to override or overwrite the default route???

Answer (score 0):

The files in the `/public` aren't overrideable, as far as i know.
You could move the favicon.ico from your /public folder to /public/images  and define a custom route:

```rb
get 'favicon.ico', to: "favicons#show"
```

Then, in the favicons controller you can check the current domain from the request and return the according favicon based on that.

```rb
class FaviconController < ApplicationController
  def show
    host = request.host
    # Find the corresponding favicon file based on the host

    send_file file.path, filename: 'favicon.ico', disposition: :inline
  end
end
```

To make sure that you don't have to make a request for the default favicon every time, define a favicon_tag in your layout if it hasn't already been defined -

```rb
= favicon_link_tag '/images/favicon.ico'
```